# SQLite missing database

Tags: sql, database, firefox

I have two database named **Main** and **OutputTax** using Firefox SQLite database.My aim is to update database in **OutputTax** while data in **Main** is input by selecting certain columns.

The columns in **Main** are  "*Date*", "*Particular*", "*InvNoSimp*", "*InvNoFull*", "*AmountTaxSimp*", "*GSTSimp*", "*AmountTaxFull*"

While I just need "*Date*","*Particular*","*InvNoSimp*","*AmountTaxSimp*", "*GSTSimp*", in **OutPutTax** database.

> String query=**"insert into OutputTax SELECT
>   Date,Particular,InvNoSimp,AmountTaxSimp,GSTSimp, from Main";**

Whenever I call this query, It shows Query does not return results.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem? Thank you, your answer is much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds obvious, but are there any rows in `Main`?

Comment: @RichardTownsend Yes, it is the input data. I need to update OutputTax database once Main database data is input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
insert into OutputTax( Date,Particular,InvNoSimp,AmountTaxSimp,GSTSimp) SELECT 
Date,Particular,InvNoSimp,AmountTaxSimp,GSTSimp from Main;
```

Comment: The column in OutputTax is Date","Particular","InvNoSimp","AmountTaxSimp", "GSTSimp". Do you know how to slove it?

Comment: I have tried your answer but it stated syntax error. But when I reinsert the SELECT in to the line it shows Query does not return results again. Is that related to the Mozila Firefox sqlite?

Comment: There are two situations right now. 
**1****String query="insert into OutputTax SELECT (Date,Particular,InvNoSimp,AmountTaxSimp,GSTSimp) from Main";**
**2**.String query="insert into OutputTax SELECT Date,Particular,InvNoSimp,AmountTaxSimp,GSTSimp from Main";**
While **1** is with bracket and **2** is without. 
When **1**is used, it stated **SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error)**
When **2** is used, it showed ** Query does not return results**

Comment: For this answer :   insert into OutputTax( Date,Particular,InvNoSimp,AmountTaxSimp,GSTSimp) SELECT 
Date,Particular,InvNoSimp,AmountTaxSimp,GSTSimp from Main;
It stated Query does not return results too :(